# Cannot use spring cloud config and istio 1.1.1 together-cannot recover when HTTP 404 error to get remote config

Tags: spring-cloud-config, istio

when I'm tring to mix the spring cloud config with istio 1.1.1, When my app container(with istio envoy auto-injected) starts, the spring cloud config client will try to get config(applicationContext.yaml) from remote cloud config server(started in advance with good status), unfornately it fails with HTTP 404 error. Even if I've configged my app to have retry for cloud config client, it keeps retring alway with HTTP 404 error(I've confirmed the config server URL is correct from another container) and there's no chance to recover. It happens **sometimes**. I knew that Istio envoy and my app are in the same kubernetes POD, the app may start before istio envoy, in which case there might be network error but as soon as the envoy is up, everything should be OK. I really don't understand why my app cannot recover automatically. Here're my diagnostic steps:
**1. Add retry mechanism in my app(with retry libs included in POM and modified yaml. - retry works but each retry failed with HTTP 404 error**
`spring-config/
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        initial-interval: 10000
        max-attempts: 100`

**2. Add 'sleep xx' before my java app starts in my app k8s deployment file - less chance to have HTTP 404 error, but problem is not eliminated**
`command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 20; java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m app.jar"]`
**3. get the istio envoy's access log and compare the victim app's and good app's - it sounds like the good log has values for upstream_cluster and upstream_cluster key; the fields for the bad log are empty**
the good access log
`{
 "response_code": "200",
 "user_agent": "Java/1.8.0_121",
 "response_flags": "-",
 "start_time": "2019-06-25T01:17:29.661Z",
 "method": "2019-06-25T01:17:29.661Z",
 "request_id": "d3d27512-161b-4303-bb48-05a6e19e05b7",
 "upstream_host": "172.20.3.104:9083",
 "x_forwarded_for": "-",
 "requested_server_name": "-",
 "bytes_received": "0",
 "istio_policy_status": "-",
 "bytes_sent": "1144",
 "upstream_cluster": "outbound|9083||fota-spring-config.ns-fota.svc.cluster.local",
 "downstream_remote_address": "172.20.2.115:45816",
 "path": "/fota-spring-config/fota-task/dev/master",
 "authority": "fota-spring-config.ns-fota.svc.cluster.local:9083",
 "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
 "upstream_service_time": "289",
 "upstream_local_address": "-",
 "duration": "290",
 "downstream_local_address": "172.21.1.152:9083"
}`
the bad access log:
`{
 "upstream_cluster": "-",
 "downstream_remote_address": "172.20.2.118:41980",
 "path": "/fota-spring-config/fota-dmserver/dev/master",
 "authority": "fota-spring-config.ns-fota.svc.cluster.local:9083",
 "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
 "upstream_service_time": "-",
 "upstream_local_address": "-",
 "duration": "0",
 "downstream_local_address": "172.21.1.152:9083",
 "response_code": "404",
 "user_agent": "Java/1.8.0_121",
 "response_flags": "NR",
 "start_time": "2019-06-25T01:21:24.197Z",
 "method": "2019-06-25T01:21:24.197Z",
 "request_id": "346716e4-1def-465f-b370-cb1e71e30d25",
 "upstream_host": "-",
 "x_forwarded_for": "-",
 "requested_server_name": "-",
 "bytes_received": "0",
 "istio_policy_status": "-",
 "bytes_sent": "0"
}`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to load into istio enabled pod a remote config file?

Comment: yes you're right.

Comment: As you mentioned the sprint config server is a service in mesh, why don't you safe the config as ConfigMap or put share it over PV?
Also please post the deployment files.

Comment: ConfigMap is an alternative, but I'm trying to understand why Istio does not work with spring config server.

Comment: Hi there, do you fix it? We got the same problem via istio1.6 and springcloud config center

Answer (score -1):

The Kubernetes deployment file:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fota-car
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fota-car
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: fota-serviceaccount
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: uaes-docker2
      containers:
      - name: fota-car
        image: 192.168.119.22:18080/uaes-fota/fota-car:dev-release-1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8085
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:mysql://mysql-ali-dev.ns-fota-ext-svc/fota-car?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-ali-dev-secret
              key: username
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-ali-dev-secret
              key: password
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c","java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m app.jar"]
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 18085
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 1
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fota-car
  name: fota-car
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8085
  selector:
    app: fota-car
```